# nested cursor loop in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I am new to postgresql, and get a problem about nested loop.Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE q_39442172
(
   id character varying,
   event_id character varying,
   createdat character varying
);


insert into q_39442172 values('id1', 'event_1', '20160789');
insert into q_39442172 values('id2', 'event_2', '20160689');
insert into q_39442172 values('id3', 'event_3', '20160679');
insert into q_39442172 values('id4', 'event_4', '20160579');
insert into q_39442172 values('id3', 'event_3', '20160579');
insert into q_39442172 values('id2', 'event_5', '20160379');
insert into q_39442172 values('id1', 'event_6', '20160339');


create or replace function query_event_sequence() returns table( r_id character varying, r_events text ) as
$$
declare
    vc_id            character varying;
    vc_event_id      character varying;
begin
    for ref_User in execute 'select distinct id from q_39442172 order by id' loop
        vc_id   := ref_User.id;
        r_id    := ref_User.id;

        for ref_Event in execute 'select event_id from q_39442172 where id = ' || vc_id loop
            vc_event_id := ref_Event.event_id;
            r_events    := concat_ws( ',', r_events, vc_event_id );
        end loop;

        raise notice '%: %', r_id, r_events;
        return next;
    end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

The exception i get:

```
NOTICE:  id1: event_6,event_1
ERROR:  cursor "<unnamed portal 2>" already in use
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function query_event_sequence() line 13 at OPEN
********** Error **********

ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 2>" already in use
SQL state: 42P03
```

Actually, using array_agg can do what i want to do, but i am just confused about why nested cursor loop in my code won't work.

Comment: Why are you collecting all those IDs in a single big comma separated string? That doesn't make sense (at least to me). What are you trying to do with those IDs?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I run this code just for pratice, and what i want to know is that how to use nested cursor loop in postgesql.

Comment: Your example is incomplete. `ref_User` and `ref_Event` are not declared anywhere. Could you post the complete code and the complete error message, please?

Comment: When I add the missing declarations for the records, this works for me. Where and how are you calling the function?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  when using cursor with for loop, you do not need to declare cursor variable. This is complete code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use psql. It still not work. Could you paste your code ?

Comment: I get "*loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables*" without declaring the records `ref_user` and `ref_event` If I add those to the `declare` section, your code runs without and other modification.

Comment: I'd say that if that code works without ddeclaring those variables, you must be using something other than plain PostgreSQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't know what is wrong. I use postgres 9.5.4 and psql to connect to server.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Did you have a try ?  I try adding the declare but it still not work.

Comment: As I said, post the complete code and the complete error message and I can try.

Comment: Thanks. Creating the function fails with **loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables**. What PostgreSQL are you using? What do you get for `SELECT version();`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  PostgreSQL 9.5.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Comment: I can't believe that the above code works there. Sorry, but I can't help if I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It is all right, thinks.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, it strikes me as weird that the error message mentions line 13, when no cursor is opened anywhere near line 13. The error message cannot be from the execution of this function, unless the function is different from what you posted.

Comment: The function does not even compile, the question cannot be answered

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't why, the code i paste here is the same as mine.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Forget the issue, do not waste your time on it.

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico  Forget the issue, do not waste your time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function or a cursor for this. A single SQL statement will do:

```
select string_agg(concat_ws(',', event_id, id), ',' order by id)
from q_39442172 
where id in (select id from q_39442172)
```

Comment: Thinks for your answer. String_agg does work, but why it won't work when using nested cursor loop in postgresql ?

Comment: What i want to know is how to make this code work, any suggestion?